# What is an i3d file, and how can I read it?

Tags: file-format

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I find out about an unknown file extension?](https://superuser.com/questions/273968/how-can-i-find-out-about-an-unknown-file-extension)

What is the .i3d file extension? How can I read/edit such files?

(Googling isn't helping much, because "3d" is a common term.)

**Edit:**

The file comes from an <del>iOS App</del> Draw Somethin, and it almost certainly isn't a 3d image file.

Comment: A file name extension does not dictate content, it could be arbitrary.

Comment: have you tried opening it with a text editor? is it binary or text?

Answer (score 3):

Well I tried google and dug up [something](http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/i3d)

> Three-dimensional texture file created by Houdini, a professional modeling and rendering program; can store arbitrary volumetric data in 3D space; often used for storing clouds or smoke.

search term was `.i3d file`

Actually seems that more programs, like maya or blender, are able to handle these kind of files.

btw: If you want to search for a specific phase and don't want google to autocorrect it you can put it between quotes, too. eg: `"i3d"`

Answer (score 1):

Well, it would help to mention what that file is from, other than an 'ios app'. I'd try opening it in a text editor. I'd also try to make use of [trid](http://mark0.net/soft-trid-e.html), which makes an informed guess of what a file is, and the file command in linux, which compares it against magic numbers.  Trid also has a online version and a filetype index

If all else fails, you may want to consider poking around a bit with a hex editor. You could then google or otherwise look up the file header.

Comment: Trid doesn't help. Probably proprietary.