# How do I open a BDC file?

Tags: file-extension

I have a file with a .bdc extension.

I've read that it's some kind of dictionary file, but I have no clue what software I can use to open it.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/273968/how-can-i-find-out-about-an-unknown-file-extension and http://superuser.com/questions/274734/is-there-a-tool-that-can-determine-the-file-type-from-containing-data may be of interest as a more general form of this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Babylon Dictionary File](http://www.babylon.com/products/babylon/)

> Dictionary file used by Babylon, an online translation tool; contains
>   terms and definitions for a specific language, such as the Oxford
>   English dictionary; used to lookup and search for the definitions of
>   words within Babylon.

You can download the application for free